# index out of range doesn't raise IndexError in Python

Tags: python, indexing, boolean

When used together with Booleans, the **IndexError** may not be raised.

For example, assume

```
list 1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

This will return **True**.

```
True or True and list1[3] > 3
```

But this will raise **IndexError**.

```
False or True and list1[3] > 3
```

Comment: First is short circuited, second is not.

Answer (score 1):

The first line will read the `True` and not continue because there is an `or` so the `list[3] > 3` doesn't matter and won't be evaluated, instead True is returned.

The second line starts with a `False` + `or` requiring it to read the next boolean expressions to return the output. It will read `True` and try to evaluate the `list[3] > 3` expression which will raise the IndexError

Answer (score 0):

This is because the nature of boolean operator
`True or True and list1[3] > 3`
since you have written this as `True or some logic`, as it encountered `True` and a trailing `or` it will simply ignore rest of the logic because a logic will always be `True` if it starts with `True` and there is a `or` in between but in case of `and` it could be `False` since `True and False` return `False` thus it will check for the rest of the logic. And your second one starts with `False` so `False` can be True if it is being followed by an `or` thus it checks for your rest of the logic where it encounters an `error`

Answer (score -1):

Because index number is till 2. List indexes begin with 0. This will work:

Make your list name right first:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

False or True and list1[2] > 3
```